# Spring Boot POST mapping with a validated form bean *and* a RequestParam gives 405 error on invalid form

Tags: spring-boot, validation, post, password-confirmation

In my Spring Boot application I have an "edit user" form, the form is bound to a SecurityUser bean, but has an additional (non-bean) field for confirming the password.  The GET mapping in my controller looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/security/user/{username}")
public String showEditUserForm(@PathVariable("username") String username, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("securityUser",securityUserService.findByUsername(username));
    return "/security/edituser";
}
```

In the POST mapping, I want to check the password confirmation input's value and compare it to the password field value, so I coded it like this:

```
@PostMapping("/security/user/{username}")
public String processEditUser(@Valid SecurityUser securityUser, @RequestParam String confirmPassword, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "security/edituser";
    }
    logger.debug(securityUser.toString());
    logger.debug(confirmPassword);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashstatus","success");
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashmessage","You successfully submitted an edituser form");
    return "redirect:/security/success";
}
```

If the form is valid, everything works fine (granted, it's just logging and a redirect to a success page).  But if any form field is *invalid*, a 405 error (HTTP method not supported) is the result.

In the logs it's:

```
2020-02-06 15:44:39.114  WARN 20496 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Originally the GET and POST endpoints were different, so I made them the same, as you can see, and that obviously wasn't the solution.  If I eliminate the @BindingResult variable from the POST mapping, the bug goes away, but then I obviously can't check the password confirmation.

**How can I access a form input *that's not a bean field* in a Spring Boot POST mapping without this error occurring?**

Comment: What happens if you move the `BindingResult` parameter right after the bean you want to validate, i.e. `SecurityUser`?

Comment: That solved it!  The method signature is now `public String processEditUser(@Valid SecurityUser securityUser, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam String confirmPassword,  RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {}`.  But why?  How???

Comment: @KrisztianToth If you can explain it I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases where the order of the argument actually matters. The `BindingResult` parameter has to be right after the object you want to validate.

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web):

> You must declare an Errors, or BindingResult argument immediately after the validated method argument.